# Is $\frac{\partial U(Q)}{\partial Q} = P$?

Tags: microeconomics

Is it true that $\frac{\partial U(Q)}{\partial Q} = P$ where $U$ is the utility function, $P$ is the output price  and $Q$ is the output quantity? Maybe not exactly this, but is something like this (possibly at the optimal value) true by any chance?

Is there any way to relate the output price and the utility function of the consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is particularly true if utility is *quasi-linear*, i.e. $V(q,m)=u(q)+m$, where $u(\cdot)$ captures the consumer's utility from the (only) good and $m$ is leftover money from consuming that good. Here $m$ can be treated as the numeraire whose price is $1$.

Given income $I$ and price $p$ of the good, the consumer's utility maximization problem is
\begin{equation}
\max_q\; u(q)+(I-pq) 
\end{equation}
The first order condition is then
\begin{equation}
u'(q)=p
\end{equation}

This is also a special case of the more general condition given in [RegressForward's answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/53336). Just take $j$ as the numeraire, and then $\frac{MU_j}{p_j}=1$, which makes $MU_i=p_i$.

Comment: I didn't follow the last part. I think you are talking of the $j$ in RegressForward's answer. What exactly do we take as a numeraire? Thank you.

Comment: @Citrus: $j$ being the numeraire implies $MU_j=p_j=1$ which in turn implies $MU_i=p_i$ (though the latter is not necessarily equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Good thinking. You're on track but not quite there.

You're thinking of the *optimal consumption rule* - you're correct it has to do with marginal utility.
Define: $\frac{\partial U(Q)}{\partial Q} = MarginalUtility = MU$

And in a two-good consumption problem, the optimal consumption is then found by:
$\frac{MU_i}{P_i}=\frac{MU_j}{P_j}$

and exhausting the agent's budget.

Comment: $\max[U(x_1,x_2)]$ subject to $p_1 x + p_2 x_2$ has the optimal condition $\frac{\text{MU}_1}{\text{MU}_2} = \frac{p_1}{p_2}$ (along with the budget condition) as you suggested. May I ask what you're referring to as $Q$?

Comment: What does the $X$ represent in your equation there?

Comment: If $X_1, X_2$ are two different goods, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ (in my comment) are the quantities consumed by the agent. I thought, that's what you meant by $MU_i$ and $MU_j$ - the marginal utilities of two goods. And similarly, $p_i, p_j$ as the prices of the same two goods.

Comment: Right, so $Q$ in these cases refers to the quantity of the good.

Comment: I misunderstood one thing. Things make sense now; thank you very much!